# OROCRM datagrid inline edit update changes value to entity ID

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I have a unique ORO CRM system, with a location table, connected to Location Entity.
It has id, name and parent fields. I wanted to make all fields editable as a following:

- name: as string
- parent: as entity selector.

Based on descriptions and on original ORO tasks-grid, i made it's datagrid, but after successful update on the parent field the parent changes to the ID of parent on the UI.

My location.yml for the datadgrid is the following:

```
datagrids:
  locations-grid:
    inline_editing:
      enable: true
    extended_entity_name: Entity\Location
    source:
      type: orm
      query:
        select:
          - l
          - p
        from:
          - { table: Entity\Location , alias: l }
        join:
          left:
            - { join: l.parent, alias: p }
      hints:
        - HINT_TRANSLATABLE
    columns:
      name:
        label: 'location.datagrid.field.name'
        align: right
      parent:
        label: 'location.datagrid.field.parent'
        inline_editing:
          enable: true
          entity_name: Entity\Location
          behaviour: enable_selected
          editor:
            view: oroform/js/app/views/editor/related-id-relation-editor-view
            view_options:
              # Related value field name
              value_field_name: parent
              placeholder: 'pélszholder'
          # Required. Specifies available choices
          autocomplete_api_accessor:
            # class: oroui/js/tools/search-api-accessor
            class: oroentity/js/tools/entity-select-search-api-accessor
            # The entity name to search in. Required for EntitySelectSearchApiAccessor
            entity_name: Entity\Location
            # Name of the search handler to use Required for SearchApiAccessor
            search_handler_name: locations
            # Optional. Name of the property that will be used as an identifier. By default = 'id'
            value_field_name: id
            # The field to search by and to show in UI equired for EntitySelectSearchApiAccessor
            field_name: name
            # This value is the visible value on the dropdown list
            label_field_name: name
    properties:
      id: ~
      view_link:
        type: url
        route: location_view
        params: [ id ]
      update_link:
        type: url
        route: location_update
        params: [ id ]
    sorters:
      columns:
        name: { data_name: l.name }
        parent: { data_name: p.name }
      default:
        name: ASC
        parent: ASC
    filters:
      columns:
        name:
          type: string
          data_name: l.name
        parent:
          data_name: l.parent
          type: choice-tree
          autocomplete_alias: locations
          renderedPropertyName: 'parent'
          className: 'Entity\Location'
    actions:
      view:
        type: navigate
        label: 'common.grid.details'
        link: view_link
        icon: eye
      update:
        type: navigate
        label: 'common.grid.edit'
        icon: edit
        link: update_link
    options:
      entityHint: 'location.datagrid.entityhint'
      export: true
      entity_pagination: true
```

Does anybady have idea, how to show parent's name after update instead of it's ID?
Tahnks in advance!

Hi Andrey!

Yes, here is my search.yml for Location Entity:

```
search:
  # Class to search in
  Entity\Location:
    # alias for searching by f.ex.: autocomplete_alias
    alias: locations
    label: 'location.search.label'
    title_fields: [name, parent]
    route:
      # name to generate url to an entity.search_handler.search_handler
      name: location_view
      parameters:
        id: id
    fields:
      - name: name
        target_type: text
        target_fields: [name]
      - name: parent
        relation_type: many-to-one
        relation_fields:
        -
            name:                   name
            target_type:            text
            target_fields:          [parent]
    search_template: Common:Partials:searchResult.html.twig
```

Comment: Hi DennissHun,
Can you please, share the search engine configuration for the parent entity?

Comment: For attempt i just tried to run the same codes in another machines, and seems like the problem was in the environment, but still not able to run on the original one.

Tried ```oro:message-queue:consume``` and ```cache:clear``` commands also.

Is it possible, i need to clean or rebuild something before use the feature?

Comment: the most reliable way to apply all the code changes in the oro platform is running `php bin/console oro:platform:update --force --env=prod`. It warms up all the caches and rebuilds JS assets.

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Unfortunatelly it didn't solved the problem. I tried with --env=dev also.
Would you have other idea to solve it?
Thanks!